# Metro App Create Email Address Entry Xaml Control

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

How do I create a `Control` to input email addresses, similar to how capturing tags on `stackoverflow` works?

I am using C# and Xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need:

TextBox(to show input area where you can type)

Popup(to show suggestions below TextBox like StackOveflow does)

ItemsControl(it goes into Popup, so you can just have collection of items and they will be displayed, note that ItemsPanel should be probably GridView)

Then you will need custom Button, that will be overlaid top of TextBox once tag has been added. You need to calculate how big is the button(width) and fill TextBox with empty spaces, to advance cursor further.

Also you need to control what keys are being pressed.

Comment: Thanks! Used most of your recommendation to achieve what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

The effect you are after is probably that you recognize complete e-mail addresses, and render them in a custom way. I would do this by removing the completed addresses from the textbox, and wrap them in a skinned label (or maybe a custom control with a delete button).

The most straightforward way is to implement the textbox as a `DockPanel` with a border, suggesting that it is a text box. On the left side of your `DockPanel`, you have a `StackPanel` where you stack the completed address controls left-to-right. Then add a textbox with `DockStyle=Fill` to fill up the remainder of the `DockPanel`. Once you detect an email address is entered, you remove the characters from the textbox and add a matching control to the `StackPanel`.

There is probably a way to change the textbox contents without losing focus, otherwise you need to fix this though code.

Good luck!